# Get an Invalid karma.conf file message, and Karma Configuration page makes no sense to me

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I made karma.conf.js using karma init and a tutorial. When I run karma start karma.conf.js, I get "Invalid config file  files: [" and some syntax info that means nothing to me. The Karma Configuration page http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html is not helpful because it has no examples for the code statements provided. I'm using karma, jasmine-core, karma-jasmine, karma-chrome-launcher, and a few others.

I think the problem is some combination of not knowing what to put in basePath: and not knowing how the files: array should be set.

I have basePath: "",  The Karma Configuration page says the following code will access any .js file, so I used it.

```
files: [
  '**/*.js'
],
```

I have tried some other things like

```
 ./src/client/app/*.js  //and 
 **/**/**/*.spec.ts
```

and they all generate Invalid config file messages.

My folder structure is

```
MyProject
  src
    client
      app (has the Angular2 app component and a 1st.spec.js test file)
        components
          input (contains html, ts and css files for Angular2 components)
          navigation
          search
          etc.
```

The 1st.spec.js file contains the simple tautology test

```
describe('1st tests', () => {
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

How can I get this test to run?

Comment: Using the command "node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js" , I get the Invalid config file - Unexpected identifier message with anything I put in the files: array.  Using "npm test" where test is a package.json script for "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"" , I get hundreds of error messages about dependency modules in node_modules - and "Test failed".  I added "exclude: [node_modules, typings]  but the hundreds of errors continue. What's going on?

Comment: I now added "pattern: 'node_modules/@types/core-js/*.ts', included: false, watched: false," to the files: array expecting that core-js would not be included in the test running, but I continue to get hundreds of errors listed and "Test Failed" at the end.  What's going on with karma?

Comment: OK, the Invalid config file message results from an missing comma for the frameworks: array above the file: array.  An expletive is in order, after 6 hours of work on this. The npm test command still generates hundreds of errors that are not in my code. However, the node node_modules . . . command creates a karma response.  That karma response says I need an adapter that implements the _karma_.start method.  I have karma-chrome-launcher, so this is still a puzzle.

Comment: The SO question about "need an adapter that implements the karma.start method" has dozens of different answers - they all work for someone. I added yet another.  In my case, changing basePath from "../" back to " " got karma working, of course, after fixing a missing comma, etc.  TDD may be the best thing since beer in a can, but its evident that for many developers, karma is not easy to set up and start working. It took me over 8 hours.

Comment: See my answer at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707262/an-angular2-app-with-karma-jasmine-throws-errors-with-multi-level-directory-st/42097977#42097977